# Pipe external process's output into running C++ script

Tags: c++, stream, terminal

I am making a simple bash terminal with the SFML framework for C++. I understand how to begin an external process with the system() fn, but I need a way to stream a child process's output into the current script. Is there a simple way to do this? Perhaps using an fstream hack? I am using Unix.

Comment: Which OS? There's popen on linux that might do what you want

Comment: It is a POSIX function, not only on Linux. ;-)

Comment: @DejanLekic I'd rather be safe than sorry :) All I can claim is that it's on my linux OS, but thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [pipe()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe)s - . The basic idea is to [fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) then to [dup2()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) the file descriptors 0 (stdin), 1 (stdout) and, respectively, 2 (stderr) into the specific pipes and then to [waitpid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) in your "main" branch of the  fork until you get an `WIFEXITED` on the "child" branch.